# Flag as Community Wiki?

Tags: discussion

See this question:
[Wordpress programming video tutorials](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/32506/wordpress-programming-video-tutorials)

It certainly doesn't fit the WPSE Q & A format, but the question could potentially add value, e.g. as a Community Wiki. So, I've not voted to close, but am unsure how to indicate a suggestion that it should be made into a Community Wiki. What is the correct approach?

1. Comment on question
2. Moderator flag: other
3. Vote to close as Not Constructive
4. Other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the future, if you see a question you think should be converted to a community wiki, I'd suggest flagging it for moderator attention *and* leaving a comment explaining why.

Just leaving a comment doesn't bring it to our attention to make the conversion in the first place.  But often times, just flagging doesn't give us enough information to understand your arguments.

Community Wiki should be reserved for generic questions to which there is no one right answer.

In this specific case, there is no one right answer ... but even then it's such a broad question that I don't think it would qualify anyway.  Yes, the question and answers might provide value ... but "I have no idea where to start, please list all the resources you know that have anything to do with WordPress" isn't very productive.  It's asking for a shotgun approach to development rather than "what are the best resources for developing a child theme?" or "what are the best tutorials for setting up an ecommerce plugin?"

Answer (score 0):

As for me this falls under best practices in scope. Where do I find WordPress-specific documentation (scope) in specific form of video (question itself).

There is no defined workflow for "make CW" suggestion, since CW had been overused in network and now being scaled down. I'd say if there is no issue with question other than that it seems like CW (which is somewhat vague thing) then just move on.

Comment: What "best practice" is being requested, or can provide an answer to the question as posed? This is a **list of resources** question, not a **best practice** question.